# Rx Scheduling/Blocking Issue: Subscribed OnNext called not executed on Timer sequence

Tags: system.reactive

I'm completely stumped on this. Only been working Rx for a couple of days and it's clear there is a fundamental exception in my understanding somewhere..so after trying numerous ideas based on various articles I need some expert eyes on it to point out what I'm not seeing...

I am trying to test some code I have written which simulates a polling mechanism. I am using the Microsoft.Reactive.Testing TestScheduler to provide a "virtual timeline" I can advance the timeline to quickly simulate a large number of polls over a long period of time...very useful indeed:

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

// create the sequence of polls (each poll returns a string)
var observeable = poller.CreatePollingSequence(scheduler);

observeable.Subscribe(
           item =>
           {
                Debug.WriteLine(item));

           },
           _ => Debug.WriteLine("Completed!"));

scheduler.AdvanceBy(60*1000* TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
```

Here's the implementation for CreatePollingSequence. *Note "PollResult" is a simple class which contains a list of strings representing a number of rows returned from the poll.* e.g PollResult(1) generates a result containing one string of text.

```
   public  IObservable<PollResult> CreatePollingSequence(IScheduler scheduler)
    {

        return Observable.Create<PollResult>( 
            (IObserver<PollResult> observer) => 
            {
                 return  scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (sched, ct) =>
                  {
                    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), scheduler)
                       .Subscribe(_ =>
                    {
                            observer.OnNext(new PollResult(1));

                    });

                   await sched.Yield();
                   observer.OnCompleted(); // end of sequence


                   return Disposable.Empty;
                });

            });




    }
```

So this all appears to work OK (although I'm not entirely sure of the rationale of some lines at this point in my Rx journey nor the overall correctness even...).

But this is the key issue: When I change the offsetTime argument to ObserveableTimer to a non-zero value  (in order to simulate an initial poll at time *dueOffsetTime*)  things start to go astray. Specifically, the code which subscribes to the sequence returned by *CreatePollingSequence* suddenly never executes. To re-iterate, ***it does when the OffsetTime argument of the Timer sequence is zero***. As you can see from the code I have begun to suspect this could be some form of deadlock on the scheduler when the sequence returned by Timer is generated at any other time other than immediately...hence the appearance of .Yield and the use of ScheduleAsync...but I'm acutely aware I have not identified the actual issue, so I cannot be sure what resolving code should be. Hence this question - hope someone can point out what's wrong...Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what `CreatePollingSequence` is supposed to do, but I think this does it more concisely, and works for non-zero offsetTime:

```
public IObservable<PollResult> CreatePollingSequence(IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler)
        .Select(_ => new PollResult(1));
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

In response to your question, no you don't need to call `observer.OnNext` explicitly. The `Observable.Timer` will do that for you. I recommend you try swapping out your code for mine.

Rx wraps around `IObservable` and `IObserver` in much the same way LINQ wraps around `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` (or for that matter `IQueryable`). In LINQ-land, if you're calling `enumerater.MoveNext()` directly, you're probably doing it wrong: The whole point of LINQ is to take advantage of the flexibility/concatibility of the Enumerable monad, so you're calling relatively high level, chainable functions (LINQ operators).

Similarly with Rx, the goal is to use Rx operators as much as possible, and to avoid calling Observer or scheduler methods directly. You can make it work, it's just much harder to maintain, read, support, etc.. If I were reviewing your code, I would cite the following problems:

- `Observable.Create` is pretty much like implementing your observable, something you want to avoid doing.
- Calling the Scheduler directly is another thing that is error prone. Your code can lead to deadlocks, since it isn't yielding.
- You're subscribing to an observable (the `Observable.Timer` subscription), but not disposing or tracking that subscription. This can lead to memory leaks.

In summary, use easy code. It makes kittens happy.

Comment: Ok..interesting, more concise definitely, but seems to result in no execution of the OnNext action in the observer's subscription call?? Surely I need to call observer.OnNext within the Timer subscription? In fact I have since been advised offline to here that the solution is to remove the outer ScheduleAysnc....but I don't fully understand why.

Comment: I'm not fully clear on what you're trying to do. If you make that clear, I can help with the Rx part.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to simulate a single value being polled, and integrate that with an `IScheduler` for testing purposes. Please correct if wrong.

Comment: Yes, pretty much, Actually simulation of a long running poll (of a db) where each poll could return n records. Configurable poll interval and will probably next apply buffering to ensure poll results are "batched" to polling client.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked this out. I think! It's a simple stupid bug. I had the observer.OnCompleted() call in the wrong place, in fact it was never being called at all. It should have been the second argument to Observeable.Timer.Subscribe (see code below). The ScheduleAsync is also superfluous.

```
 public IObservable<PollResult> CreatePollingSequence(IScheduler scheduler)
    {

        return Observable.Create<PollResult>(
            (IObserver<PollResult> observer) =>
            {
                return scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (sched, ct) =>
                   {


                        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler)
                            .Subscribe(_ =>
                            {

                                // make this configurable...i.e actual data returned!!!
                                //    GetData();


                                observer.OnNext(new PollResult(2));



                            }, () => observer.OnCompleted());



                    return Disposable.Empty;
               });

            });




    }
```